# Why can't this be a primitive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, primitive

I was messing around with JavaScript, and noticed that `this` can never be a primitive.  What am I talking about?  Let me explain.

Take this function for example.

```
function test(){
    return typeof this;
}
test.call('Abc'); // 'object'
test.call(123); // 'object'
```

They are both `'object'`, not `'string'` or `'number'`, like I'd expect.

After a bit of confusion (and messing with `instanceof`), I figured out what's going on.  `'Abc'` is being coverted to a `String` object, and `123` is being converted to a `Number` object.

Anyway, my question is why does this happen, and how do I convert an object back to its primitive?

I know I could use `(String)this` or `(Number)this`, but how can I do that if I don't know the type?

**EDIT**: I was trying to do this:

```
function element(){
    var $e = $(this),
    $d = $e.closest('div');
}
element.call('#myID');
```

and it wasn't working.  `this` is a `String` object, and jQuery just made a collection of objects instead of using the selector to search the DOM.

Comment: it's probably in the spec somewhere http://es5.github.com/

Comment: Whoa, that is not what I would have expected.

Comment: BTW, your `element` function there totally doesn't need to use a `this` at all.  It's too tricky for it's own good.  `function element(selector)` would obviously avoid this whole thing.

Comment: @AlexWayne: I probably should do it that way :-P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others noted, it's coerced to an object as per the spec.

Important thing to note is that if you're in *strict mode*, the coercion doesn't happen.

```
"use strict";

function test(){
    return typeof this;
}
test.call('Abc'); // 'string'
test.call(123); // 'number'
```

So the real question is ***why aren't you using strict***? ;-)

---

As you noted in your comment, you should be able to use `.valueOf()` if you're supporting implementations that don't support strict mode.

If you're only expecting a String, or if you're also expecting a Number, but you don't mind a numeric String instead, you could do this...

```
(this + '') // "Abc"
(this + '') // "123"
```

> *"but how can I do that if I don't know the type"*

If you want to know its type, use the generic `toString` available on `Object.prototype` to get the internal *[[Class]]* property.

```
Object.prototype.toString.call( this ); "[object String]"
Object.prototype.toString.call( this ); "[object Number]"
```

Comment: The hell?  Why would strict mode do that?

Comment: @Rocket: Probably to give the user the expected value. Strict mode really doesn't monkey with `this` too much. If you just did `test()`, then `this` would be `undefined` instead of the global object.

Comment: Cool, this totally works.  I realized that `valueOf` also works.  Thanks.

Comment: and what about browsers that don't support `"use strict"`?

Comment: @zzzzBov: Good point. @Rocket's `.valueOf()` solution should work. ...or if a String is always expected, do `(this + '')`

Comment: yea, testing [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SdN2n/) in IE (which doesn't support `"use strict"`) doesn't produce the expected results.

Comment: I need to support IE, so I can't use strict.

Comment: @Rocket: I'd suggest you still use strict, but just don't rely on techniques that are only valid in strict. In other words, use strict, but stay compatible.

Comment: @amnotiam: I just need `this` to be a string, because I'm using `$(this)`.  If `this` is an object, jQuery returns me a collection of objects (even if it's a `String` object), it won't do a DOM lookup.  `$(this+'')` works ok.  Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 3):

I found it, [ECMAScript 5.1](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.4)

#### Function.prototype.call

> NOTE The thisArg value is passed without modification as the `this` value. This is a change from Edition 3, where a `undefined` or `null` thisArg is replaced with the global object and `ToObject` is applied to all other values and that result is passed as the `this` value.

Basically it says `undefined` and `null` as the first parameter cause `this` to be the global object (`window` in a browser context), and all other values are converted to an object using [`ToObject`](http://es5.github.com/#x9.9).

---

Due to the inconsistencies of `typeof`, I recommend using `Object.prototype.toString.call`, which returns consistent values in every browser I've tested:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call('foo') //[object String]
Object.prototype.toString.call(10000) //[object Number]
Object.prototype.toString.call(someFunc) //[object Function]
...etc
```

[you can compare the output in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SdN2n/4/)

Comment: At least this is documented and isn't some strange behavior :-)

Comment: Thanks for `Object.prototype.toString.call`, `typeof` just returns `'object'`.  This is slightly more useful :-)

Comment: Is there a way to just get the type (without `[object...`), or should I just do `Object.prototype.toString.call('foo').match(/\[object (.*)\]/)[1]`?

Comment: You could use a hash to store the value conversions that you want: http://jsfiddle.net/SdN2n/3/ I typically just check `thetype === '[object Array]'` or whatever type i need to check.

Answer (score 2):

The [spec says](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_10.4.3) that `this` is always an object.

> Else if Type(thisArg) is not Object, set the ThisBinding to ToObject(thisArg).

Comment: Seems strict mode doesn't call `ToObject` (as 'am not i am' pointed out).

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is, `this` makes no sense outside an object-oriented context, it will always be pointing to some object's instance. So by definition it cannot be a primitive.

Also, it seems your test function is returning the `typeof` the `test` function itself (which is `this` in that context), and not of the parameters you're passing.

Comment: I'm using `call` to set `this` inside the function.

Comment: Er, sorry, you're right, I didn't notice that. However, I still think it would be very strange to assign a primitive to `this` (because of what I said on the first sentence from my answer).