# why this is output as the following?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var obj = [ "one", "two", "three"];

$.each(obj, function() {
   console.log(this);
});
```

The output I get is

```
{ '0': 'o', '1': 'n', '2': 'e' }
{ '0': 't', '1': 'w', '2': 'o' }
{ '0': 't', '1': 'h', '2': 'r', '3': 'e', '4': 'e' }
```

I suppose to get "one" "two" "three", but I get the following weird results, anyone can explain?

Comment: because that's what the object really looks like, like all javascript objects. Keys and associated values. If you just want to log the values, do that :)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039121/why-cant-this-be-a-primitive

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt: That's not quite what's he's asking.  He's why it's an object (and not a string).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` is always an object there. A string object consists of key/value pairs where keys are indices and values are characters at that index in the string. Try `Object("foo")` to create such an object yourself.

By using strict mode you can suppress that:

```
$.each(obj, function() {
  "use strict";
  console.log(this);
});
```

Comment: Funny, [the jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) don't mention "use strict" at all.

Comment: This is true.... however, for clarity, I would advise against using the `this` keyword like this.

Comment: @MattBall: Why would it?  This is a JavaScript thing, not just jQuery.  It's in the JS spec, that `this` is *always* an object (outside of strict mode).

Comment: Also, IE does not support strict mode until 10: http://caniuse.com/#feat=use-strict, so this code would bomb your script in IE

Comment: @Chris: That's true; the OP asked for an explanation why it didn't work.

Comment: In case anyone is curious, here's the JS spec that says that `this` will always be converted to an object: http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_10.4.3 (or http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.4)

Comment: @pimvdb: Yes, I just realized that, and added a new link to my comment ^_^

Comment: @pimvdb With all due respect, sir, this is NOT "why it doesn't work". This is "misuse a language feature with no cross-browser support to arbitrarily change this behavior". The fact the strict mode "suppresses" the behavior is arbitrary, not an intentional feature. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/xzVBc/

Comment: @Chris: I think it is intentional because the spec explicitly states it. In your fiddle, the object doesn't go through the coercion process like everything else - but it's an object itself so that's what you get.

Comment: @Chris: What are you talking about?  This behavior is 100% documented, and therefore an real feature.

Comment: Look. `this` is always an object -- that's the spec. WHAT `this` references is also defined by the spec, but it can be changed using `bind`, as I did in my fiddle. If jQuery didn't change the `this` scope of the loop passed to `$.each`, `this` would reference `window`: http://jsfiddle.net/BVLFr/. jQuery changes the scope to the loop item. That is not in the jQuery documentation, and it isn't reliable (since you can easily change it)

Comment: @Chris: I'd like to ask you if you're using strict mode or not. If jQuery did not do that, `this` would be `undefined` in strict mode.

Comment: @Chris: `The value can also be accessed through the 'this' keyword, but Javascript will always wrap the this value as an Object even if it is a simple string or number value.`.  From the jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: If you do use strict mode, you should use it at the script level: http://jsfiddle.net/xWXfH/ In that case, unbound functions have `undefined` as their scope. If you bind them to something, then `this` will not be undefined, strict mode or not: http://jsfiddle.net/EebDC/

Comment: Look guys, my point is that `this` is changeable, using "use strict" **just** to mess with what it is in an `$.each` loop isn't a good idea, and that it isn't how `$.each` was designed to be used. That's it.

Comment: @Chris: I'm not saying that objects aren't allowed in strict mode. I'm merely saying that the object coercion does not take place. If you don't use anything, it's `undefined`; if you use an object, it's that object. Anyway.

Comment: @Chris: `this` is only changeable by *YOU*, the programmer.  If YOU changed, then YOU should know what it is.  `"use strict"` is not "messing with it", it's using a new feature :)  P.S. `$.each` *was* designed to be used that way :-P

Comment: *sigh* I really think you're missing my point on strict mode. It is bad practice to sprinkle "use strict" in an each loop function **just** to change what `this` is.

Comment: @Chris: Ah, I see what you are trying to say now.  Sorry for arguing.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, that makes sense. I'm sorry :)

Answer (score 4):

In javascript (not just jQuery), `this` is a special keyword referring to an object bound to the current scope (unless it has been changed). Within the `$.each` function, the scope context of the loop function (the function you pass) is bound to the item that you're looping. That may be the case, but it isn't reliable nor is it very useful or interesting.

Observe:

```
var clams = { 'tomato!':'gross' };
var items = ["one", "two", "three"];


$.each(items, function (index, item) {
    console.log('this',this);
    console.log('item', item);    
}.bind(clams));
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/LBfet/

While it is possible to use `this` within an `$.each` loop, I would suggest using it the way the documentation provides, which is that your looping function support the signature `callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement)`.

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Consider it a quirk.

**More Reading**

- The this keyword* on quirksmode - http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html
- `jQuery.each` - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: The first paragraph there talks about `this` by saying it's an object.

Comment: `this` is **always** an object, it is the function scope reference. You can change the scope. jQuery changed the scope of the looping function to be an item. You can change it to something else with `bind` (the javascript method, not jQuery)

Comment: If you're talking about non-strict mode, then you're correct. I'm not sure if I agree with the terminology, though. Scope is about the variables that you have access to; `this` is not really related to that.

Comment: `this` is exactly related to scope. It's what `this` **is**; an object bound to the current scope: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this You can change the scope with the `bind` function, which jQuery does with `$.each`.

Answer (score 2):

What's happening here is that jQuery is using `.call` to set the value of `this` inside the callback to `$.each`.

When `.call` is called, the value of `this` is converted to an object (as per the JavaScript spec: http://es5.github.com/#x10.4.3).

This is also noted in the jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

> The value can also be accessed through the `this` keyword, but Javascript will always wrap the `this` value as an Object even if it is a simple string or number value.

"Strict mode" (which only works in modern web browsers, so not IE: http://caniuse.com/#feat=use-strict) actually changes this behavior and allows `this` to be a primitive (this is documented in the spec: http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.4):

```
$.each(obj, function() {
  "use strict";
  console.log(this);
});
```

You can also use `.valueOf()` to convert the object back into its respective primitive:

```
$.each(obj, function() {
  console.log(this.valueOf());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A javascript string, down to the basics, is an object. This object is broken down into an array of characters. This is why you can call some of the same functions on a string object like an array.

Any time you manipulate a string literal, in this case, it is changed to a string object. A string object is an array of characters. This would allow for easily capitalization when using functions like: toUpperCase() & toLowerCase() - *(along with others)*

Using `this`, as others have stated, is referenced as an object. Here is a little test code to show how a string is like an array:

```
var testStr = "test";
var obj = [ "one", "two", "three"];
console.log(testStr.charAt[1]); // Will return 'e'
console.log(testStr[1]); // Will return 'e'
console.log(obj[1]); // Will return 'two'
console.log(testStr.length) // Will return 4
console.log(obj.length) // Will return 3
```

A string literal in the case of `var testStr = "string"` is a primitive data type with no functions. But a String Object is used to manipulate the data with functions and non-primitive data types.

Now I am going to create a string object and output it to console:
*(This is what happens when you manipulate a string literal, it gets converted to a string object)*

```
strTest = new String("TEST String");
console.log(strTest);
```

You will get:

```
String
0: "T"
1: "E"
2: "S"
3: "T"
4: " "
5: "S"
6: "t"
7: "r"
8: "i"
9: "n"
10: "g"
length: 11
__proto__: String
    anchor: function anchor() { [native code] }
    big: function big() { [native code] }
    blink: function blink() { [native code] }
    bold: function bold() { [native code] }
    camelCase: function (){return this.replace(/-\D/g,function(match){return match.charAt(1).toUpperCase();});}
    capitalize: function (){return this.replace(/\b[a-z]/g,function(match){return match.toUpperCase();});}
    charAt: function charAt() { [native code] }
    charCodeAt: function charCodeAt() { [native code] }
    checkAllAvailableTags: function (){var b=this,d;for(d in c)c.hasOwnProperty(d)&&(b=b.replace(d,c[d]));return b}
    clean: function (){return this.replace(/\s{2,}/g,' ').trim();}
    concat: function concat() { [native code] }
    constructor: function String() { [native code] }
    contains: function (string,s){return(s)?(s+this+s).indexOf(s+string+s)>-1:this.indexOf(string)>-1;}
    escapeRegExp: function (){return this.replace(/([.*+?^${}()|[\]\/\\])/g,'\\$1');}
    fixed: function fixed() { [native code] }
    fontcolor: function fontcolor() { [native code] }
    fontsize: function fontsize() { [native code] }
    hexToRgb: function (array){var hex=this.match(/^#?(\w{1,2})(\w{1,2})(\w{1,2})$/);return(hex)?hex.slice(1).hexToRgb(array):false;}
    hyphenate: function (){return this.replace(/\w[A-Z]/g,function(match){return(match.charAt(0)+'-'+match.charAt(1).toLowerCase());});}
    indexOf: function indexOf() { [native code] }
    italics: function italics() { [native code] }
    lastIndexOf: function lastIndexOf() { [native code] }
    length: 0
    link: function link() { [native code] }
    localeCompare: function localeCompare() { [native code] }
    match: function match() { [native code] }
    replace: function replace() { [native code] }
    rgbToHex: function (array){var rgb=this.match(/\d{1,3}/g);return(rgb)?rgb.rgbToHex(array):false;}
    search: function search() { [native code] }
    slice: function slice() { [native code] }
    small: function small() { [native code] }
    split: function split() { [native code] }
    strike: function strike() { [native code] }
    sub: function sub() { [native code] }
    substr: function substr() { [native code] }
    substring: function substring() { [native code] }
    sup: function sup() { [native code] }
    test: function (regex,params){return(($type(regex)=='string')?new RegExp(regex,params):regex).test(this);}
    toFloat: function (){return parseFloat(this);}
    toInt: function (){return parseInt(this,10);}
    toLocaleLowerCase: function toLocaleLowerCase() { [native code] }
    toLocaleUpperCase: function toLocaleUpperCase() { [native code] }
    toLowerCase: function toLowerCase() { [native code] }
    toString: function toString() { [native code] }
    toUpperCase: function toUpperCase() { [native code] }
    trim: function trim() { [native code] }
    trimLeft: function trimLeft() { [native code] }
    trimRight: function trimRight() { [native code] }
    valueOf: function valueOf() { [native code] }
    __proto__: Object
```

Comment: In your example: `console.log(testStr)` is `"test"`, but in the OP's example, `console.log(this)`" is `{ '0': 'o', '1': 'n', '2': 'e' }`.

Comment: @Rocket But as others have stated using `this` in a looping function treats it as an object, I am giving a background in to why it is still treated like an object instead of a string

Comment: But not why it is an object in the 1st place, and not a sting.

Comment: @Rocket A String is an Array Object of Characters for what every you may put in it. You have to think logically on the best way to store and be able to manipulate with functions for capitalization (not limited to).

Comment: Sorry to burst your bubble, but strings are *not* objects.  They are primitives. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Glossary

Comment: @Rocket A String object is an array. Create a string object and output it to console and you will see exactly what I am describing. I have updated my answer with a console.log output

Comment: @Rocket Check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String. States: `Note that JavaScript distinguishes between String objects and primitive string values.`

Answer (score 0):

As **this** is an object you can simply use the toString method to output its contents.

```
$.each( obj, function() {
    console.log( this.toString() );
});
```

Comment: I think you can use `this.valueOf()` too :P

Comment: Agree. In the case presented `this.toString()` still works but for other datatypes like numbers it converts them into strings. Although with other objects such as dates both methods will pose problems as they have their own implementation of valueOf() method.

Answer (score 0):

Why the output is what it is: As pimvdb says: this is a pointer to an object. jQuery *applies* the anonymous function as a callback to each value. If that value isn't an object, jQ will make it into one. Hence, three objects are logged.

Couple to that that strings are, for computers, one of *the hardest things to cope with*! It's just a series (array) of chars. That's why, in C, and many other languages the string type doesn't (didn't) exists. A string is an array, and since Arrays are augmented objects in JavaScript (first version didn't even have them), you get the output you get. 
It's not that big of a problem, though:

```
obj = [ "one", "two", "three"];

$.each(obj, function()
{
   console.log(this+'');
});
```

Solves this (somewhat). But add `typeof this` and you'll see it still is an object, add `this instanceof String`, and you'll get true. To get rid of those pesky string objects (they are pesky), and get clean string constants:

```
obj = [ "one", "two", "three"];

$.each(obj, function(i,el) {
   console.log(el);
});
```

That's it: instead of applying the function as a method, jQ will now pass the key and value pair as arguments, where i is the key and v is the value.

Comment: "If that value isn't an object, jQ will make it into one".  That's not true.  jQuery doesn't do anything.  `this` is an object, because that's what's in the JS spec.

Comment: `this` is always something... it refers to the object scope. You can change the object scope, which jQuery does in the `$.each` loop. If it didn't, `this` would refer to the function itself, or the `window` object. The spec states that `this` an object, but it can be literally any object... depends on what the natural scope is, and whether the scope is changed.

Comment: @Chris: this never refers to the function itself unless you're augmenting the function object. Inside a function `this` points to the parent object, which is either some object or the global object (window is a property of the global object that points to the nameless global object. Window isn't an object itself) @Rocket, jQ doesn't do this explicitly, but the source does `callback.apply(obj[i],args);`, which converts the value to an object. Granted: inherent to the JS spec, not jQuery

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem That is not strictly true -- `this` can refer to several things "naturally" (that is, without binding), though I guess I don't know what you mean by "augmenting the function object", unless you mean "extending the `Function` host object prototype" -- that isn't the only time `this` may be a function object. `this` == scope (unless changed), which can be a function. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/WrWh9/. I am not sure we actually disagree on anything :) Except... `window` **is** an object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window).

Comment: @chris, well in your fiddle, _this_ points to t, the function is actually a constructor, t is an object and its constructor is an anonymous function. But since functions _are_ objects I must conceive that you have a point (except: `console.log('this in constructor', this); console.log(this === arguments.callee);//<-false`... reference the function itself: this !== the function, but its return object. By augmenting the function object I mean things like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866483/styling-makes-javascript-code-not-function-properly/11867005#11867005), not the best example